# Fix command line output

Tags: command-line

[Command line showing problems I need help fixing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hA1uc.png)

I currently completing a assignment for a placement application and I am trying to run the program from an input command line statement but it is not giving me any output as all these errors are printed. This command line program is written in the java environment.

```
C:\Users\Spencer Du\Documents\MSc Computing with placement Cardiff Uni\EMBL-EBI Assignment task\pia-1.3.10>java -cp pia-1.3.10.jar de.mpc.pia.intermediate.compiler.PIACompiler -infile C:\Users\Spencer Du\Documents\MSc Computing with placement Cardiff Uni\EMBL-EBI Assignment task\MSFragger-20190222\MSFragger-20190222\1a-QExHF04026.pepxml -outfile de.mpc.pia.intermediate.compiler.PIACompiler
[23-Mar-2019 18:32:38 - INFO] "file: C:\Users\Spencer
        name: Spencer
        type: null
        additional info file: null" (de.mpc.pia.intermediate.compiler.PIACompiler:1342)
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/logback-classic-1.1.6.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.6.1.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
18:32:38,377 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback.groovy]
18:32:38,377 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Could NOT find resource [logback-test.xml]
18:32:38,378 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Found resource [logback.xml] at [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/jmztab-modular-model-3.0.8.jar!/logback.xml]
18:32:38,378 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs multiple times on the classpath.
18:32:38,378 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/jmztab-modular-model-3.0.8.jar!/logback.xml]
18:32:38,378 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/px-submission-core-2.0.15.jar!/logback.xml]
18:32:38,378 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/jmztab-modular-util-3.0.8.jar!/logback.xml]
18:32:38,378 |-WARN in ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext[default] - Resource [logback.xml] occurs at [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/jmztab-modular-converters-3.0.8.jar!/logback.xml]
18:32:38,386 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.ConfigurationWatchList@a4102b8 - URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/Spencer%20Du/Documents/MSc%20Computing%20with%20placement%20Cardiff%20Uni/EMBL-EBI%20Assignment%20task/pia-1.3.10/lib/jmztab-modular-model-3.0.8.jar!/logback.xml] is not of type file
18:32:38,438 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - debug attribute not set
18:32:38,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Setting ReconfigureOnChangeFilter scanning period to 30 seconds
18:32:38,441 |-INFO in ReconfigureOnChangeFilter{invocationCounter=0} - Will scan for changes in [[]] every 30 seconds.
18:32:38,441 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - Adding ReconfigureOnChangeFilter as a turbo filter
18:32:38,445 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction - Adding LoggerContextListener of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator] to the object stack
18:32:38,463 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@11dc3715 - Propagating DEBUG level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
18:32:38,463 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerContextListenerAction - Starting LoggerContextListener
18:32:38,463 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - About to instantiate appender of type [ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender]
18:32:38,465 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderAction - Naming appender as [console]
18:32:38,469 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.NestedComplexPropertyIA - Assuming default type [ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder] for [encoder] property
18:32:38,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.LoggerAction - Setting level of logger [uk.ac.ebi.pride.jmztab] to ERROR
18:32:38,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@11dc3715 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[uk.ac.ebi.pride.jmztab] onto the JUL framework
18:32:38,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.RootLoggerAction - Setting level of ROOT logger to ERROR
18:32:38,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator@11dc3715 - Propagating ERROR level on Logger[ROOT] onto the JUL framework
18:32:38,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.AppenderRefAction - Attaching appender named [console] to Logger[ROOT]
18:32:38,492 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.action.ConfigurationAction - End of configuration.
18:32:38,493 |-INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.joran.JoranConfigurator@69930714 - Registering current configuration as safe fallback point

SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [ch.qos.logback.classic.util.ContextSelectorStaticBinder]
E|JDBCAccess                              |Cannot open the SQLite DB: C:\Users\Spencer via JDBC
E|JDBCAccess                              |SQLite-Error -       SQLState:       0       SQLMessage:     opening db: 'C:\Users\Spencer': Access is denied
E|JDBCAccess                              |JDBC-Error(JDBC): No connection to the database
```

Thanks
Spencer

Comment: Post the errors here as text.

Comment: I have updated the post with the errors

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava

Comment: Search the web for the last error: `JDBC-Error(JDBC): No connection to the database`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava Is that all I need to fix everything. A connection to the database?

Comment: You would need to find that out yourself :)

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I tried but still not sure.